# How can non-Muslims read a physical copy of the Quran?

Tags: quran, fatwa, mushaf

According to [this fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/10672), you can't touch the Quran (mus'haf) if you have major or minor impurities. However, [some scholars](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2156/can-quran-be-touched-without-wudu/2159) think that you can touch the Quran with minor impurities, but not with major impurities:

when the Quran eventually appeared in the form of the mus'haf, what were non-muslims supposed to do if they wanted to read the Quran?  For example, Arab Christians that were only able to speak Arabic. In modern day, people have the internet and they can read the Quran online, how would they have read the Quran back in the day? As stated in the two links above, Muslims sin for touching the mus'haf if we were not free from major and/or minor impurities based on the majority of Islamic scholars. What about non-muslims?

How would non-muslims in the past have read the Quran if they couldn't touch it as they wouldn't be appropriately cleansed from major and/or minor impurities?  Would they have sinned by touching it?

Comment: Does this mean that every non-Muslim, by definition, has a "major impurity?" Is that the basic premise of the question? And having this major impurity of not being a Muslim, thus shouldn't be allowed to touch the Quran?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have read about the incident of Hadrat Umar (RTA) before he accepted Islam, we see that his sister did not let him read the Holy Quran because he was impure and asked him to take a bath first. He took a bath and it was only then his sister let him read the Quran and after that he visited Prophet Muhammad pbuh and accepted Islam. No fatwa here, just referring an incident.

Comment: please provide source so that others can refer to it fully