# Is it permissible to read the Quran without wudhu?

Tags: wudu, quran-recitation

Is it permissible to read the Quran without wudhu?

Can a Muslim read the Quran without wudhu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Qur'an be touched without wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2156/can-quran-be-touched-without-wudu)

Comment: @Pureferret, the dupe mentioned is about touching the quran. But this post is about reading it.

Comment: I believe the answers to that question answer this one, and thus is sufficient to suggest they are duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is permitted to recite the Qur'an without touching it when you don't have wudhu.

It is superior, when reasonably possible, for one to do wudu.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can read Quran without wudhu, but you should not touch the words in the Holy Quran, so in few words you can without touching.

But it’s better as you are talking with ALLAH to be ready for this by being on wudhu