# Are non-Muslims allowed to touch an English translation of the Quran?

Tags: quran, halal-haram, non-muslim

I have purchased "The Qur'an: A New Translation" by M. A. S. Abdel Haleem
(it's an English translation). My question is, am I allowed to touch it and read it?

Comment: Yes you can touch and read it, any way you like. The only purpose of this book is that human beings find guidance from their Creator

Comment: @goto '*in any way you like*' ? That's not true

Comment: you are not allowed to touch the words in pages but you can read it and learn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Qur'an be touched without wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2156/can-quran-be-touched-without-wudu)

Comment: Of course you can touch it as long as you do respect it and are ritually clean(clean hands - highly recommended | as respect). It is meant for every-one, who wants to learn lifestyle and other such matters in a religous perspective. but don't draw conclusions from the translation, as not all arabic words are appropriately translated (shortcoming of languages), even in arabic it requires high level of wisdom and knowledge to undestand **some of the verses**

Answer (score 4):

Alan: short answer, as someone already said, is yes, please go ahead and feel free to read and enjoy it.

There's a long answer I'd like to give based on the answers that have already been provided, even though you have not explicitly asked for these details.

Within the Islamic school of thoughts, there is a difference between touching the Quran and touching its translation.

M.A.S. Abdel Haleem's translation that I have does not have any original Arabic Quranic text, therefore, even within the Islamic school of thought, there is no issue with presenting it to a non-Muslim and a non-Muslim reading or touching it.

The issue with the Arabic Quran is a result of Muslim belief that the Quran is God's literal word, and thus a holy object. The same way as there are rules in various religions regarding holy objects (e.g. Old Testament for Jews, New Testament for Christians, cows and various idols for Hindus etc.), so is the discussion on what those rules are for the Quran.

Within Islamic thought, the issue is divided between those who believe that the verse 79 of Al-Waqiah (quoted by beautiful mind in their response) prohibits touching the Quran except in the state of ablution. As state in the comments to the same question, there has been a strong difference of opinion that those verses do not refer to touching the Quran rather was an assertion from God that the Quran has only been transported by angels and not any evil being, since that was an allegation put forth by the Quran's opponents. (This latter opinion looks more likely given the context of those verses and the arguments put forth by both sides.)

Dr. Khalid Zaheer, who happens to be a prominent scholar, has clarified that issue in his response (linked to in another answer here) and provided his opinion.

As for the word of Allah which someone mentioned as to be not touched without ablution, I must mention that it is not at all an Islamic or a Quran-specific word as some would have believe. It had been used extensively in pre-Islamic poetry, and it seems that bible's translations in Arabia before the advent of the Quran used this word to refer to the English God. One can easily find Arabic translations of the bible that use word Allah, and modern day Arab Jews and Christians use word Allah to talk about God -- a tradition that has been passed down to them from before Islam.

In fact, the Quran had actually argued why it differed on its concept of God (i.e. Allah) from whatever the Jews, the Christians and the polytheists of Arabia believed regarding Him. This is actually what stirred Arabia at that time because another man had claimed to be a prophet of the same God (i.e. Allah) that the Jews, the Christians and the polytheists believed in.

Answer (score 1):

Please go ahead and read the Quran and its translation.

IMO the purpose of the book is to attain guidance from God, besides how else could one of the world's largest religion be islam if our ancestors didn't touch or read the Quran

Here's the clarification for the Quranic verses stated by a brother here:

http://www.khalidzaheer.com/qa/366

Now though its clear that you can touch / read the Quran, I recommend you do a wudhu (its'very simple and easy) before you sit on reading it as this would help you refresh physically and psychologically stimulate your senses as well.

Peace, mercy and blessings of God be with you.

Mohsin

Answer (score 0):

Of course perfectly 'yes'.

The scriptures are holy it means we treat them with holiness or in other words don't misuse or mock or make fun of or don't disrespect them. That by no means mean that we're restricted from touching it without wudu (cleaning oneself with water if not with clean earth). In particular, wudu was commanded to be done before offering Salah as seen in Qur'an [5:6](http://quran.com/5/6).

Qur'an was indeed sent as a guidance to mankind, conditional, you respect it. Of course as and always...

> ...Allah doth not wish to place you in a difficulty, but to make you clean... (Qur'an 5:6)

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a bath with the intention of being clean and touch even the Arabic Quran.

Search for the full body clean in Islam. (غسل) it has got some easy conditions you should take care of.

Omar ibn Al-Khattab touched the Quran before believing in Islam, but he took a bath before doing that, as his sister demanded who was Muslim at that time.

Thanks for respecting Quran.

Answer (score -1):

According to this verse of Quran:

> "None touch it except the purified."(**Surat Al-Wāqi`ah,verse79**)

people couldn't touch Quran without Wudu neither Muslims nor Non-Muslims.On the other hand Kafir shouldn't touch the Quran specially with wet hands because he/she is najis(unclean).

You didn't mention your religion,But totally touching **translation** of Quran which doesn't have any exact Arabic word of Quran is ok.But pay attention touch the name of Allah in any language without Wudu is haram.

And Quran 's reading doesn't have any problem;But you aren't allowed to dishonor It.

reference in persian :  Towzih al-Masa'el by Ayatollah Ruhollah Khomeini

Comment: According to Ibn Abbas this is referring to the Book that is in heaven and the purified refers to the angels not to us humans. Please add references to your answer.

Comment: oh,yes.I just forgot it.thanks...but that opinion which you said isn't right.It is just an interpretation of this verse.

Answer (score -2):

All the Devine revelations came to the messengers in their respective languages. Therefore the quran was revealed in Arabic. However,  since the quran is the last revelation it must be for all mankind till the end. The quran speaks to all regardless of their language difference. It speaks to everyone in Arabic. The stories and sayings of previous generations whose language was not Arabic are quoted and related to us in Arabic in the quran for all to read. The quran does not divide people according to their differences of language, culture ,nationality, colour, etc. It divides us into three main categories as follows:
A.  Those who believe in God
B.  Those who reject  the believe in God. 
C.  Those who are hypocrates 
The quran makes this judgement AFTER IT HAS BEEN READ AND ITS MESSAGE CLEARLY UNDERSTOOD . The crucial factor here is whether or not one believes in the existence of an ALMIGHTY GOD WHO IS THE CREATOR OF EVERYTHING.  After that it does not matter what language one speaks because he/she is a Believer.  You do not NEED the quran to know GOD. People knew God since The beginning of their creation. But they kept on erring and straying from the Path that would lead to good life after death.  All revealed religions are simply a merciful guidance to that Path.  If therefor anyone wants to know more about the right then let them read the quran since they are already Muslims by definition. 
As for those who reject believe in God reading the quran will  only make them more distant. They should instead first examine their basic human intelligence as it obviously lacking. Hypocrites are worst than faith rejectors to the degree that even the rejectors do not trust them as their own

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are different then the typical internet Forum to learn moer about this site and the stack exchange model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help] and read [answer].

Comment: Instead of answering the Question you are talking about the Quran and categories of people this is not the subject of the Question!