# while reciting quran when fart comes is it necessary to do ablution(wudu) again?

Tags: wudu, quran-recitation

Asslam o alaikum all of my brothers and sisters... It is better to do ablution(wudu) before reciting quran but i have one question and my question is that before reciting quran i do wudu(ablution) but while reciting quran almost everytime i fart and then i again do wudu and again recite quran. Is it necessary to do wudu again after u fart.... Iam talking only about reciting quran not about salah because it is necessary to do wudu again when you fart in salah but is it necessary while reciting quran?? I don't know why people downvote my this question coz i haven't said something bad...

Comment: The most accepted view of the 4 madhabs generally say that wudu is obligatory in order to **touch** the Quran but reciting it does not, so you should read it without touching it. See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2156/can-quran-be-touched-without-wudu) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/can-we-complete-quran-by-reading-from-book-and-then-from-device).

Comment: Why do you keep editing the question without making any meaningful improvement?

Comment: Well good question i do coz I don't get any accurate answer according to my topic but now i got my accurate answer and i don't want to edit now i mean i will not edit now

Answer (score 0):

its necessary before touching the holy quran you have to perform ablution if in case while reciting the holy quran your ablution is broken then you perform it again to full fill the condition again which is you filled before reciting.

Answer (score 0):

I to had a similar question like you and like I did not get a real straight answer my advice is to listen to your gut feeling and see what it tells you oh and keep in mind that while reciting the holy Quran your speaking directly to the maker of all just think about that for a minute your speaking, talking, and conversing with the almighty now ask yourself should you be in a state of wudu or not. Good luck may the one God have mercy on all humanity as a whole Amin

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to differences of opinion of what it meant to be pure.

“No one should touch the Quran but one who is pure.”

What does the word pure (tahhir) mean?

There are three different answers:

1. To be pure is to be a Muslim. If you're not a Muslim you are not pure thus you should not touch the Quran.
2. To be pure is to be free of the state of junub. If you ejaculate or menstruate: you are in a state of junub and thus in need of a bath (ghusl) to purify yourself. To be pure here meant you have purify yourself by ghusl after being in a state of junub.
3. To be pure after taking wudoo’. To be pure here meant you are not a state of junub and had taken wudoo'. In this state, you can pray.

Going back to the question, what you should do depends heavily on what it meant to be pure.

What I am about to say is my opinion. Take it with a grain of salt.

With regard to the hadeeth about the purity of the believer, it was narrated that Abu Hurayrah said: “I was met by the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and I was junub. He took my hand and I walked with him until he sat down. Then I slipped away and washed myself (ghusl), then I came to where he was sitting. He said, ‘Where were you, O Abu [Hurayrah]?’ I told him, and he said, ‘Subhaan-Allaah, O Abu [Hurayrah]!, the believer does not become impure.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, al-Ghusl, 276; Muslim, al-Hayd, 556).

This heavily implies that to be a Muslim is to be pure by default. You are simply limited by what you can do such as reciting the Quran depending on your level of purity. It meant that there are levels of purity. To be a Muslim is to be pure. A Muslim that performs qhusl is purer than a Muslim that didn't. A Muslim that is in the state of wudoo’ is purer than one that is not.

*In my opinion, reading the Quran, reciting the Quran, and even touching the Quran is permitted so long as you are not in the state of junub though it is better to be in a state of wudoo' when doing it.*

I based my reasoning on the Prophet not reciting the Quran in the state of junub as well as the fact that the Quran in its codex (Mus'haf) form does not exist in the times of the Prophet.

“The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to recite Qur’aan to us in all situations so long as he was not in a state of janaabah.” (Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, al-Tahaarah, 136. al-Tirmidhi said: this hadeeth of ‘Ali is hasan saheeh)