# Is it permitted to recite the Quran without doing Ghusl?

Tags: quran-recitation, ghusl, masturbation

Asslam o alaikum to all of my brothers and sisters My question is that if you masturbate but don't do ghusal at that time, then is it necessary to do ghusal before reciting the Quran or you can recite Quran without doing ghusal????

Comment: Why should do answer of this be any different than that presented in the linked answers of your other question [While reciting qur'an when fart comes is it necessary to do ablution (wudu') again?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55020/while-reciting-quran-when-fart-comes-is-it-necessary-to-do-ablutionwudu-again) wudu' is necessary, and wudu' is not valid without ghusl.

Comment: But the answer is given.

Comment: It was written that wudu is obligatory when you touch the quran but to recite it doesn't but when you turn page of quran you should have to touch the quran so while reciting you should do wudu if your wudu broken

Comment: You may recite from your memory! In that case you don't touch anything.

Comment: This is my last question. Iam not hafiz quran so how do i know what is written on next page of quran

Comment: That is not what the point of the answer is. Reciting Qur'an doesn't require wudhu, which is what your question asked. Reciting Qur'an doesn't necessarily mean you have to turn pages of the Mushaf. One may be reciting it from memory. If you're going to touch a Mushaf, you will need wudhu. But that is a different case altogether, which was not what you asked in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

The view of the majority is that it is not permitted to recite the Quran  (even without touching the mushaf) while in a state of greater ritual impurity which requires ghusl, such as in the state of Janaabah (sexual impurity).

> عن علي قال كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يقرئنا القرآن على كل حال ما لم يكن جنبا قال أبو عيسى حديث علي هذا حديث حسن صحيح
>
> Ali narrated: "Allah's Messenger would recite the Qur'an in all conditions, as long as he was not Junub."
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/146)</sup>

Reference: [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/9435#p5) , [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/520#p1)