# What acts of worship are prohibited for a woman undergoing menstruation?

Tags: women, ibadah, menses

I know fasting, prayer, circumambulation and touching the Qur'an are prohibited to woman undergoing menstruation. What others acts of worship are prohibited?

Alternatively, I can re-frame the question to ask what actions are allowed like passing through a mosque, flight between Safa and Marwa, reading the Qur'an from memory.

Answer (score 3):

- **Prayer**: Salah is prohibited and invalid. This also includes things that come under the rulings of prayer such as سجدة التلاوة.

  > #### إذا أقبلت الحيضة فدعي الصلاة
  >
  > Give up the prayer when your menses begin
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/6/35)</sup>
- **Fasting**: Fasting is prohibited and invalid.

  > #### كان يصيبنا ذلك فنؤمر بقضاء الصوم
  >
  > That used to happen to us and we were commanded to make up the fasts
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/85)</sup>

  > #### أليس إذا حاضت لم تصل ولم تصم ‏‏.‏ قلن بلى‏.‏ قال ‏فذلك من نقصان دينها
  >
  > The Prophet ﷺ said: Isn't it true that a woman can neither pray nor fast during her menses?" The women replied in the affirmative. He said, "This is the deficiency in her religion."
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:304)</sup>
- **Hajj**: Tawaf is prohibited, no other ritual is forbidden.

  > #### افعلي كما يفعل الحاج غير أن لا تطوفي بالبيت حتى تطهري
  >
  > Perform all the ceremonies of Hajj like the other pilgrims, but do not perform Tawaf of the Ka`ba till you get clean
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/25/131)</sup>
- **Touching of mushaf**: It is prohibited just like it is [prohibited](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/51144/20218) for a person with lesser ritual impurity.

  > #### لا يمسه إلا المطهرون
  >
  > None touch it except the purified.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 56:79](http://quran.com/56/79)</sup>

  > #### لا يمس القرآن إلا طاهر
  >
  > No-one should touch the Qur'an unless he is pure
  >
  > <sup>— [Muwatta Malik](https://sunnah.com/urn/404701) etc.</sup>
- **Recitation of Quran**: There is difference of opinion on this. The majority (Hanafi, Maliki*, Shafi'i, Hanbali) hold the view that it is prohibited. This is the cautionary approach based on analogy what has been narrated beforehand about touching, on analogy with Janabah and based on the hadith:

  > #### لا يقرأ الجنب ولا الحائض شيئا من القرآن
  >
  > No one who is sexually impure and no woman who is menstruating should recite anything of the Qur'an.
  >
  > <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/131)</sup>

  Various schools admit some exceptions for example repeating some small part as dhikr or dua rather than with the intention of reciting the Quran.
- **Staying in a mosque**: It is prohibited however it is permitted when there is a reason, such as when one takes shelter in it from a danger. This is based on analogy with Janabah and the hadith below:

  > #### لا تقربوا الصلاة ... ولا جنبا إلا عابري سبيل
  >
  > Do not approach prayer ... or in a state of janabah, except those passing through [a place of prayer]
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 4:43](http://quran.com/4/43)</sup>

  > #### لا أحل المسجد لحائض ولا جنب
  >
  > The mosque is not lawful for a menstruating woman and for a person who is sexually unclean
  >
  > <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/232)</sup>

  There is difference among the madhabs on passing through a mosque without reason, it is prohibited near the Hanafis and Malikis and makruh near the Shafi'is (if it is sure that the mosque will not get contaminated with the blood).

**References:**

1. [Islamic Jurispudence according to the four schools](https://archive.org/stream/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah#page/n197/mode/2up)
2. [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/606)
3. [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://archive.org/stream/FPmfkmfk/mfk18#page/n320/mode/2up)

Comment: Muslim Book 3, Number 0587:
'A'isha reported: The Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) said to me: Get me the mat from the mosque. I said: I am menstruating. Upon this he remarked: Your menstruation is not in your hand.