# Reading book containing lots of short quran verses without wudu

Tags: quran, books

Recently my brother bought me a islamic book called dont be sad by dr aid al qarni
[image]

That is the book and it has a lot quranic verses in English
So I was wondering if I could read this book without wudu given that this book is for muslim and non muslim

Comment: This might help https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7840/35781

Answer (score 1):

A writing which has some Quranic verses within other text does not fall under the rulings of a mushaf. It is permitted to touch it without wudu. Evidence for that includes the fact that the Prophet ﷺ sent a letter to Heraclius which had an ayah of the Quran in it.

> قال ابن عباس: أخبرني أبو سفيان بن حرب: أن هرقل دعا ترجمانه، ثم دعا بكتاب النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقرأه:  بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم، من محمد، عبد الله ورسوله، إلى هرقل، و: {يا أهل الكتاب تعالوا إلى كلمة سواء بيننا وبينكم} [آل عمران: 64] الآية
>
> Ibn 'Abbas narrated:
> Abu Sufyan bin Harb told me that Heraclius called for his translator and then asked for the letter of the Prophet (ﷺ), and the former read it (thus):
>
> In the Name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Merciful. (This letter is) from Muhammad bin 'Abdullah, to Heraclius. "O people of the Scripture (Jews and Christians): Come to a word that is just between us and you that we worship none but Allah..." (V.3:64)
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/166)</sup>

Comment: What if it has quite a lot of quranic verses